# Cannot start jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I try to start (any) jupyter notebook directly, I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",     line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",     line 1784, in start
    self.launch_browser()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",     line 1742, in launch_browser
    with open(fd, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

However, if I only start jupyter on some directory, I can open notebooks through browser just fine.

jupyter version: 4.4.0

python version: 2.7.15

OS: Fedora 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem introduced in notebook=5.7.3. Running with 5.7.2 works.

> The problem was introduced in [#4260](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4260) and backported to the 5.7.x branch in [#4265](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4265).
>
> Fix at [#4340](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4340).
>
> Fix should be part of notebook 5.7.5 when it is released.

More info at [GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4303)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Anaconda for Jupyter Notebook, try using the update option. Use the following code "conda update anaconda" in the Terminal.

Comment: I do not use anaconda, I installed jupyter through pip